# form model Method not allow Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Wanted to update the entry but getting this error.
I am using laravel 5.4
Please help

1) web.php

```
Route::resource('employeeTask','employeeTaskController');
```

2) employeeTaskController

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
 $task = task::find($id);
 $task->userAssigned = $request->employeeName_txt;
 $task->title = $request->title_txt;
 $task->description = $request->description_txt;
 $task->client = $request->clientName_txt;
 $task->completionDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->completionDate_txt));
 $task->status = $request->status_dd;
$task->save();
return redirect('employeeTask')->with('message','task has been Updated Successfully');
}
```

3) editTaskPage.blade

```
     {!!Form::model($task,['method'=>'PUT','route'=>['employeeTask.update',$task->id], 'class' => 'well form-horizontal']) !!}
               some code
     {!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image: Errors]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you run `php artisan route:list` command, do you see `employeeTask.update` named route?

Comment: yes, I checked in name its present `employeeTask.update`

Comment: Did you try to call it as PATCH?

Comment: Yes but same error

Comment: Did you Put your `Route` under an auth middleware?

Comment: Please remove the `PUT` method in your form (`editTaskPage.blade`) and use `POST` and lets see if it improves

Answer (score 0):

Your function requires an argument that is `id`

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Instead do this

for form

```
 'method'=>'POST'

public function update(Request $request)
{
    $task = task::find($request->id);
```

And add html

```
<input class="hidden" value="{{$id}}" name="id" />
```

And route

```
 Route::post('employeeTask','employeeTaskController@update');
```

Comment: Please post HTML let me make a route

Comment: https://github.com/codefactree/task

Controller: employeeTaskController
model:task
View: editTaskPage